# In Filemaker, is it possible to import into Container fields from XML?

Tags: filemaker

The [XML FMPXMLRESULT grammar](http://www.filemaker.com/help/html/import_export.16.30.html) documentation states:

> XML export does not support exporting container field data.

which seems to imply that it's possible to *import* (it does also specify that you can denote a field as type "CONTAINER" in the XML). However, I have found zero documentation as to how this might be done.

Is it possible? I get that there are ways of getting e.g. an image file into Filemaker after the fact, but can I just specify it in the XML beforehand, negating the need to have additional scripts or post-processing the import (not to mention something that works in Filemaker 11 or below)?

Comment: What exactly would you like to import - given that XML contains nothing but text, and container fields are designed to contain images or files?

Comment: @michael.hor257k importing images, preferably from http

Answer (score 1):

You can import file references, but not binary data. (And you'll have to specify the field as `TEXT` type in the XML file.) For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FMPXMLRESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult">
  <ERRORCODE>0</ERRORCODE>
  <PRODUCT BUILD="01-25-2011" NAME="FileMaker" 
      VERSION="ProAdvanced 11.0v3" />
  <DATABASE DATEFORMAT="M/d/yyyy" TIMEFORMAT="h:mm:ss a" 
      LAYOUT="" NAME="" RECORDS="" />
  <METADATA>
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" TYPE="TEXT" NAME="Path" />
  </METADATA>
  <RESULTSET FOUND="">
    <ROW>
      <COL>
        <DATA>image:test.jpg</DATA>
      </COL>
    </ROW>
  </RESULTSET>
</FMPXMLRESULT>
```

The path must be in FileMaker format; here I used a relative path to `test.jpg` in the same directory as the file (will only work for local files), but it can also be an absolute path, e.g.:

```
imagewin:/C:/Some/Path/test.jpg
```

Comment: but then you have to configure the field on the filemaker side to be a container? or a calculated container?

Comment: A container; a container can contain both binary data or text data; the latter it tries to interpret as a file reference. But this implies you have configured the FileMaker side already. If you specify field type as `CONTAINER` in XML it simply won't import any data from it. If your goal is to produce a XML and use it to create a new table in FileMaker with container fields and data, I see no easy way to do it (maybe with two files: one creates the fields and another adds references, but even this needs to be tested).

Comment: ok I think this comment here is the answer I was trying to get to

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is probably to import Base64-encoded data, then use the [Base64Decode](http://www.filemaker.com/help/13/fmp/en/html/func_ref1.31.13.html) function to decode it.

Comment: I found this answer to be most helpful for a similar need, but it doesn't meet the OP's requirement of FM11 compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

> importing images, preferably from http

I am not sure what exactly that means. If your XML contains a link to an image, then the only thing you can do with it is import the link **as text**. If you are using version 12 or higher, you can follow this with the [Insert From URL](http://www.filemaker.com/help/13/fmp/en/html/scripts_ref1.36.50.html#1095981) script step (for each imported record).

Comment: I can cURL the image to disk beforehand if need be. I'm trying to find out how to specify a container field in the XML somehow, to avoid needing to run any scripts in Filemaker. I've updated the question.

Comment: @JackJames I am afraid you are still not being entirely clear. A container field can contain either a reference (i.e. a path) to the image (on local network only!) or the image itself. If your XML document contains the local path to the image file, then you can import it, and the target container field will show the referenced image. -- Not sure why you want to avoid scripts; it's like saying you want to play football with one foot only.

Comment: if i can do it all in the XML, then the data is independent of the filemaker file.

Comment: @JackJames Data is data. The process of importing data is not data, and it cannot be confined to the source XML document alone. You must set up the import on the target (Filemaker) side, too - for example, selecting the target table and mapping the source contents into the target table fields. Typically, this part is scripted, and any post-processing that may be required (and it often *is* required) is scripted alongside with it. -- Anyway, this has very little to do with your original question.

Comment: sorry but I don't agree. an xml file can be used to create a new filemaker pro database, and xml can be created without a filemaker license.